# angular-datatables ReferenceError: $ is not defined using Dot net core angular 4 template

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I have created a Angular 4 with dot net core application using visual studio template. 
I want to use datatables in my app and tried to follow steps using https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started
But I received error as : ReferenceError: $ is not defined. 
I tried to use import * as $ from "jquery"; But did not work.
Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some more information, clarify your question, and format it correctly (put code in a code block). Otherwise, it will be very difficult to answer your question helpfully. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't follow https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started for a .Net Core - Angular Application. The setup requires `.angular_cli.json` and since you're not using `ng serve`, it will not work that way.

Possibly you can add CDN .js packages on your ASP .NET `index.cshtml` file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And add css on your `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

Please check and let us know if that works. Good Luck.