# ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined at angular-datatables.directive.js:80:21

Tags: angular, angular-datatables, angular15

Getting the below error When I used Angular-Datatables in Angular 15

```
re.mjs:8416 ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at angular-datatables.directive.js:80:21
    at timer (zone.js:2405:41)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at core.mjs:23892:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23892:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24193:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:487:34)
h
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need jQuery. See: [ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined at angular datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997256/error-referenceerror-is-not-defined-at-angular-datatables) and [the docs](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started).